# unable to access actuator endpoints spring boot 3

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have created a spring boot 3 application, where I have added spring security and spring-boot-starter-actuator, I am unable to access http://localhost:40911/actuator/health

I have a spring security configuration like below

```
return http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/api/company","/api/authenticate","/actuator/**").permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests().anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(jwtAccessDeniedHandler)
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthorizationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .build();
```

I am unable to add the below configuration in yml file

```
management:
  security:
    enabled: false
```

I am getting the below error

```
{
   httpStatusCode: 401,
   title: "Full authentication is required to access this resource",
   message: "Full authentication is required to access this resource",
   path: "/error"
}
```

**application.yml**

```
management:  
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include:
          - "*"
          - logfile
        exclude:
          - env
          - threaddump
      base-path: /admin
      discovery:
        enabled: true
  endpoint:
    health:
      enabled: true
      show-details: always
  health:
    circuitbreakers:
      enabled: true

resilience4j:
  circuitbreaker:
    instances:
      project-service :
        failureRateThreshold: 50
        automaticTransitionFromOpenToHalfOpenEnabled: true
        waitDurationInOpenState: 10000ms
        slidingWindowType: COUNT_BASED
        slidingWindowSize: 2
        minimumNumberOfCalls: 10
        eventConsumerBufferSize: 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Error response shows path: "/error". It means your request can't be handled for some reason and server want to show you the error page. But this is not allowed by the security settings. Hence 401.

**Solution**

Add `/error` to the list of permitted requests. After that you will probably see the error page and the real cause. Like "404 - Not found".

Depending on the real cause you should check the url used. Maybe you need to change the port number or add context path.

Comment: I have added /error into the permission list after I am getting 404
{
    "timestamp": "2023-07-09T04:57:43.280+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/actuator/circuitbreakerevents"
}

Comment: This is exactly what I meant. Now you know the real cause of the error: you are trying to call an endpoint that doesn't exist. Try to call localhost:40911/actuator to get the list of valid actuator endpoints.

Comment: Once I did this I came to know there was something on yml config, but I couldn't figure out what is the issue

Answer (score 0):

The way I configured reslience4J was not proper, so I have like below it works.

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include: '*'
management.endpoint.health.show-details: always
resilience4j.circuitbreaker:
  configs:
    default:
      registerHealthIndicator: true
      slidingWindowSize: 10
      minimumNumberOfCalls: 5
      permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState: 3
      automaticTransitionFromOpenToHalfOpenEnabled: true
      waitDurationInOpenState: 5s
      failureRateThreshold: 50
      eventConsumerBufferSize: 10
```